# AWS Cognito combined with other Rest apis except api gateway

Tags: authorization, amazon-cognito

**Cognito** is a powerful tool yet it's so hard to utilize it .
Trying to implement my business logic  I ended up in some dead ends and I need some help.

My client app is an **admin panel** where a new **admin** can register providing a **company**.

Now there are 2 applications (Contests, Reviews)   based on these companies .
So from the adminPanel the admin can create events for both apps through 2 different rest apis

The concept is 1 admin is related to 1 or more companies.I have to map that relationship somehow with Cognito .
Because cognito does pretty much well authentication but not *authorization*.

In every request not only I have to validate the user by the access token but I also have to see if the user is authorized to do the action based on the company.

For example if a user want to create a **Contest** event for his company. 
I will make a request to **Contest Api** and I have to authorize that the admin is related to this company

Company entities  are used  from both apis so I have to expose them in a new api called companies.(If any api wants information about companies it should call the get **company/{id})**

My consideration is that in order to authorize a user in my apis I have to:
1) validate the  access_token .
2) communicate with **Cognito** to get user informations.
3) call companies api to check if user is authorized to execute actions for this campaign.

So I kind of feeling that it becomes too complex and I need 2 services to authenticate and authorize each request(cognito + company api).
Is there any other way to implement cognito  authorization logic without having to use a second api ?

**P.S** I have already check cognito triggers but they don't cover my needs .For example **pre token generation trigger** can add claims but it will add them in **identity_token** not **access_token** .Also my claims has to be an array of company_ids that an admin is related but claims supports strings and numbers only

Comment: In one sentence what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to accomplish authorization with cognito and a non API Gateway Rest api. 
I use user pools and I know that with identity pull you can solve the authorization problem but for other AWS services .not for a non amazon api